# Trying to configure openldap TLSCipherSuite

Tags: tls, openldap

I have an openldap server, and I'm trying to tune my `TLSCipherSuite` settings to be as secure as I can have them.

Please do not critique my actual security settings.  Please just help me understand what is happening.

I am editing the `/etc/openldap/slapd.conf` file, and I am using `slaptest` to convert that file into the `/etc/openldap/slapd.d` configuration directory.  I am using `sslscan` to list the ciphers available for use.

I started with

```
TLSCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:-SSLv2:+SSLv3
```

and `sslscan` tells me

```
$ sslscan --no-failed hostname:636  | grep Accepted
Accepted  SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  256 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Accepted  SSLv3  256 bits  CAMELLIA256-SHA
[...]
Accepted  TLS12  112 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
Accepted  TLS12  112 bits  ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
Accepted  TLS12  112 bits  RC4-SHA
Accepted  TLS12  112 bits  RC4-MD5

$ sslscan --no-failed hostname:636  | grep Accepted  | wc -l
72
```

From there, I took out MEDIUM

```
TLSCipherSuite HIGH:-SSLv2:+SSLv3

$ sslscan --no-failed hostname:636  | grep Accepted  | wc -l
57
```

Better.  Then I tried to remove SHA1, and here's where I get completely confused.

```
TLSCipherSuite HIGH:-SSLv2:+SSLv3:-SHA

$ sslscan --no-failed hostname:636  | grep Accepted  | wc -l
91

$ sslscan --no-failed hostname:636  | grep Accepted
[...]
Accepted  TLS12  112 bits  RC4-SHA
Accepted  TLS12  112 bits  RC4-MD5
Accepted  TLS12  56 bits   EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA
Accepted  TLS12  56 bits   DES-CBC-SHA
Accepted  TLS12  0 bits    ECDHE-RSA-NULL-SHA
Accepted  TLS12  0 bits    NULL-SHA
Accepted  TLS12  0 bits    NULL-MD5
```

So my question is ... what happened here, that I tried to **remove** some ciphers from my accepted list, and instead, I **added** a bunch?  What did I do wrong?

Again, please do not critique my actual security settings.  Please just help me understand what is happening.